# Is it possible to convert text displayed in the App into the locale language of the downloaded location

Tags: android

In my App I have given Help option as a App usage guidance to the users. Currently it is in English.

Is it possible to convert this Help text into the locale language of the downloaded location? or Is it possible to convet this to some intented languages?

Thanks

Comment: Is [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just rough idea,

If **you have a all languages string in String.xml files.**

And **from the device timezone, if you can set the appropriate language string**, then **may be it possible**,

This is some ugly way, but if you want to try

Let me know if this is not a right idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure the logic you said is wrong or right ... but nice idea :-). But still I am looking for some API based way to auto-convert the language text instead of giving each language-specific strings in XML.

Comment: seems this is the only way ... :-)